# Android getIntent on new activity is NULL when calling activity is destroyed

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

Do you guys have a workaround for the following problem?

In the onDestroy of a registration activity (when the user presses the back button) I call a new activity so the user can put in some final production data of that day and then the report is being e-mailed. The problem is that on the just started activity the call to getIntent returns null and I have to get the data from there.

```
public void onDestroy(){
  //unregister listeners, cancel timers etc.
  logOff();
  super.onDestroy();
} 

protected void logOff(){
  // collect data etc.
  // open new activity that asks for final production numbers
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AksProductionNumbers.class);
  intent.putExtra("TimeSheetList", timeSheetList);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

===============================================================================
Constructor called activity:

```
public AksProductionNumbers(){
    Intent intent = getIntent(); // <-- returns null
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
}
```

The function getIntent returns null. I think it is because the calling activity is already dead but I think it is weird because I clearly ask the framework to start the new activity before closing the current.
Does anyone knows a workaround for this problem? I chose for this solution so I didn't have to override the 'back' button.
Another solution is to block the calling thread until it gets the unblock signal from the starting app but I think that is ugly as well. A third data manager class could also solve the data source issue. 
Thanks for ideas and advice!

Comment: I think it's bad UI. There's nothing I hate more in Android apps than hitting the back button and not reaching the previous activity (or home screen if there's no previous activity).

Comment: post more code and a logcat so we can understand the problem better

Comment: I think you should put this Intent intent=getIntent(); Bundle extraas = intent.getExtras(); on "onCreate()" on new activity

Comment: You should read more about activity lifecycle - [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) i.e. when to register and unregister listeners.

Comment: @Eran, well the user is ending the activity and upon that point (and exactly there) we'd like to know the some data (that is only available at that point). See it like a popup asking 'Where do you want to save your file' when you close a program. It is a highly specific business application - not a regular play store app. The alternative is a button on the screen to end the registration but that will leave the action of the back button unclear and ambiguous.

Comment: @Jim, I don't know what code to post; the rest is business code. The logcat tells me there is a nullpointer on the line 'intent.getExtras();'.

Comment: @asylume is it still wrong if I want the sensory information and timers to continue if the app is running in the background?

Comment: just implement `SoftCoder` suggestion and tell the result!!

Comment: it isn't clear where you make the call to "AksProductionNumbers" - just to illustrate that the rest isn't just "business logic" - I'm not sure that you have the problem that you think you have...

Comment: @SoftCoder you got it right! I still had problems, onCreate was not called in the presence of the constructor. When I removed the constructor, onCreate was being called. I still find android a weird world.

Comment: @Harmen For any background work while app is closed, use [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: You overrode constructor which was used by parent class - `Activity`, so it prevented any other important events from happening...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I think I know what your problem is. I believe you are making this call:

```
 public AksProductionNumbers()
```

in your activity *constructor* (as you state in your question) when you should be making it in the activity's `onCreate` method. `getIntent` will return null in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this

```
 Intent intent = getIntent(); // <-- returns null
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

on "onCreate()" method of new activity